# How to enable CTRL+4/5/6?

Tags: keyboard

On Mountain Lion 10.8.2, when I use the Keyboard Viewer, I can see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> register correctly when I type them.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> however, only show the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key being hit and the numbers ignored.

**How can I enable all the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`#` keys?**

I don't really need them for spaces - rather, I need all the keys available for SC2 (FWIW, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> work fine in SC2, but the higher numbers don't).

Comment: That's very strange. FWIW all those key combos work fine for me on 10.8.3. Did you check to see if the 4 and 5 keys register without modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue of unresponsive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> keystrokes using OS X 10.8.4 and found a solution that worked for me using information from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91680/62220).

1. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` (I used XCode).
2. Update keys for the shortcuts which are giving you trouble by switching `enabled` to `NO`. I switched `120` and `121`, which represent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. I am not sure about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.
3. Restart your computer.

Hope this helps!